# How to enable traceId in logback.groovy for logs in order to trace request. for Appoptics

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, log4j, agent

How to enable ao.traceId in logback.groovy for logs in order to trace request. my system is integrated with App-optics, normal logs are showing on the App-optics dashboard using paper trails plugin. However, From the App-optics dashboard, TraceId is mentioned which I unable to find in logs files. its agent is already integrated with apache-tomcat-9.0.37. similarly, I followed their documentation for integration. here is my logback.groovy

```
appender("dailyAppender", RollingFileAppender) {
    file = "logs/stacktrace.log"
    append = true
    rollingPolicy(TimeBasedRollingPolicy) {
        fileNamePattern = "logs/stacktrace.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
        if ( currentEnvironment == Environment.TEST) {
            maxHistory = maxHistoryDays
            cleanHistoryOnStart = true
        }
    }
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = "%date [%thread] %-5level %logger{15} %X{ao.traceId}- %msg%n"
    }
}
```

and javaagent.json as below

```
cat javaagent.json
{
    "agent.serviceKey":"......",
    "agent.logging":"info",
    "agent.jdbcInstAll":false,
    "agent.sqlSanitize":1,
    
    "monitor.jmx.scopes": 
    {
        "java.lang:type=MemoryPool,*":["Usage"],
        "java.lang:type=Memory":["HeapMemoryUsage", "NonHeapMemoryUsage"],
        "java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,*":["CollectionTime"],
        "java.lang:type=Threading":["ThreadCount"],
        "java.lang:type=OperatingSystem":["ProcessCpuTime", "AvailableProcessors", "ProcessCpuLoad"],
        "java.lang:type=Runtime,*":["Uptime"]
    },
    "monitor.jmx.enable":true,
    
    "profiler" : 
    {
        "enabled" : true,
        "excludePackages" : ["java", "javax", "com.sun", "sun", "sunw"],
        "interval" : 20
    }
}
```

note: I am using grails 3.0.16, java 1.8, log4j 1.2 and slf4j
reference link: https://documentation.solarwinds.com/en/Success_Center/appoptics/content/kb/apm_tracing/java/configure.htm#trace-context-in-logs

Answer (score 0):

now working, actually, it was conflicting with Datadog agent which I installed previously.